# .NET Core 2.2 endpoint from aside data provider

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I exercise with .NET Core and have a task to create an endpoint for my frontend (I'm using Vue.js) using a data provider, such as OpenWeatherMap. I do know how to address to this provider directly and send requests with Axios. But how can I do this with .NET Core 2.2? 
Currently I have two directories in my project folder where I run Vue.js frontend and .NET Core backend respectively. I guess that I must create some sort of a variable aka `baseApiUrl` and assign url from OpenWeatherMap to it but I don't quite understand where I should do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Vue project there should be a folder named config and has your enviroment variables (production and development) a valid approach is creating a baseApiUrl variable there and it accessable throught your application via this command

```
process.env.baseApiUrl
```

Edit: all configurable variables in .NET Core are defined in the appsettings.json, you can have multiple settings files for each enviroment or deployment. Then after you can access it via IOptions interface you can dig more into it it's easy to learn.

Comment: Thank you for this comment but I was asking about where in the backend I must create a variable with the provider url.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to have an api key from OpenWeatherAPI. After that you can actually make simple requests to OpenWeatherAPI using postman to test if API Key is working.

Once you have everything set up, you can actually use HttpClient library of .NET Core, to make api calls like below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"<-----Tested URI HERE-------->");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            /* Read JSON from stringResult */ 
    }
```